# How to get Google drive refresh token automatically

Tags: php, api

I am using php to upload files automatically to Google drive using API/Token, but I discovered that the Token expired after certain of time.

I always get new token from Oauth play ground Page
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

So, how to refresh it automatically using Refresh Code Token

Here is the full code:-

```
global $GAPIS;
$GAPIS = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
$name = $name;
$file = $zip_file_name;

$mime_type = 'application/zip';
$access_token = 'token';

$ch1 = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media');
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($file));
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: '.$mime_type, 'Content-Length: ' . filesize($file), 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token) );

$response=curl_exec($ch1);
if($response === false){
 $output = 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch1);
} else{
 $output = $response;
}

curl_close($ch1);  

$this_response_arr = json_decode($response, true);

if(isset($this_response_arr['id'])){
    $this_file_id = $this_response_arr['id'];
    $ch2 = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $GAPIS . 'drive/v3/files/'.$this_file_id);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');

    $post_fields = array(); 
    $this_file_name = explode('.', $name);
    $post_fields['name']=$this_file_name[0];

    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post_fields));
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token) );

    $response=curl_exec($ch2);
        if($response === false){
         $output = 'ERROR: '.curl_error($ch2);
        } else{  
         $output = $response;
        }

    curl_close($ch2);

    $print = json_decode($output, true);
        if ($this_file_name[0] = $print['name']) {
        echo "file uploaded successfully and ";
        }
}
unlink ($file);die("Zip file removed");
return $output;
```

**EDIT: Solution:-**
Thanks a lot for  ***Ronak Dhoot*** about his solution and here is the CURL code to get the refresh token automatically

```
$client_id = 'client_id';
$client_secret = 'client_secret';
$refresh_token = 'refresh_token';
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';

$fields = [
    'client_id'      => $client_id,
    'client_secret'  => $client_secret,
    'refresh_token'  => $refresh_token,
    'grant_type'     => 'refresh_token'
];

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$access_result = json_decode($result, true);
$access_token = $access_result['access_token'];
echo $access_token;
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Going through documentation pages may help you https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Step 1 when Click “Authorize APIs” and allow access to your account when prompted. There will be a few warning prompts, just proceed.

When you get to step 2, check “Auto-refresh the token before it expires” and click “Exchange authorization code for tokens”.

[image]

When you get to step 3, click on step 2 again and you should see your refresh token.

[image]

Now, All you need to do is a post request like below :-

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "client_id": <client_id>,
  "client_secret": <client_secret>,
  "refresh_token": <refresh_token>,
  "grant_type": "refresh_token"
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough Ronak, works perfect. and I updated my post with your solution

Comment: Nice answer, well-elaborated :-)